# SiteCore urls without .aspx extension

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I want to have pages accessed as if they were folders. For example:

```
domain.com/state
domain.com/state?val=xxx
```

But I can only get:

```
domain.com/state.aspx
```

How do I configure Sitecore to ignore the `.aspx` extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Sitecore web.config, set **addAspxExtension** to **false** in LinkManager

```xml
<add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
```

After doing this, you also need to map wild card extensions in IIS

Comment: I didn't have to map wildcards, just change the app pool to integrated mode instead of classic.

Comment: Interesting.  I would have thought the extension mapping was required also.  Good to know!

Comment: Just remember running in Integrated mode using Windows or Basic authentication the pool will be very fragmented. See the "Pool Fragmentation" section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches to this depending on your version of IIS. [This SDN scrapbook entry](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Friendlier%20marketing%20URLs%20for%20Sitecore%206.aspx) covers the scenarios and provides sample code.

You can also [read more](http://sdn.sitecore.net/reference/sitecore%206/dynamic%20links.aspx) about how the dynamic item URLs are generated.

Comment: I did find some useful info here. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't a Sitecore configuration issue, it's IIS.  You need to set up your site in IIS so that ASP.NET is handling all extensions.

[Here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=19304) is a thread about this topic in the SDN forum.